# navigationBarHidden() Not working in iOS 15 Beta SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios15

I am trying to hide the Navigation bar on the 3rd tab but for the rest tabs, it should show up. It workes fine in iOS 14, but in iOS 15 the modifier randomly workes. As soon as I start switching between tabs the navbar starts showing up on the 3rd tab as well. Below is my SwiftUI file Code

*NOTE*: This is just a simple representation of a more complex code setup I have for my app.
Xcode: 12.5.1
Device: XR (iOS 15 beta)

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab: TabType = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                ForEach(TabType.allCases, id: \.self) { tabType in
                    switch tabType {
                    case .profile:
                        ThirdView()
                            .navigationBarHidden(true)
                            .tag(tabType)
                            .tabItem {
                                Label(tabType.title, systemImage: "plus")
                            }
                    default:
                        SecondView()
                            .tag(tabType)
                            .tabItem {
                                Label(tabType.title, systemImage: "star")
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("2nd view")
            NavigationLink("3rd view", destination: ThirdView())
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text("3rd view")
        }
    }
}

enum TabType: CaseIterable {
    
    case home
    case discover
    case profile
    case more
    
    var image: Image {
        switch self {
        case .home:
            return Image(systemName: "plus")
        case .discover:
            return Image(systemName: "plus")
        case .profile:
            return Image(systemName: "plus")
        case .more:
            return Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }
    
    var title: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch self {
        case .home:
            return LocalizedStringKey("home")
        case .discover:
            return LocalizedStringKey("Discover")
        case .profile:
            return LocalizedStringKey("Me")
        case .more:
            return LocalizedStringKey("Shop")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `navigationBarHidden` has always been slightly glitchy. Maybe attach it to your `TabView` instead, then add a `@State var shouldHide = false` and pass it in: `.navigationBarHidden(shouldHide)`.

Comment: @aheze thanks that worked for my case, at least for now. Let's see what new surprises iOS 15 have

Comment: Not working in my case.

Comment: @Tanvirgeek can you elaborate more on your issue

Answer (score 0):

Move your `.navigationBarHidden(true)` to your `ThirdView's ZStack` like this:

```
struct ThirdView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Text("3rd view")
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Also if you do this you will lose your back button...

Make sure to remove it from the TabView first.

Lmk if it works!

Comment: I already tried placing .navigationBarHidden at different places in view hierarchy but doesnt work

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: any luck with this ? I have the same problem. Works on iOS 16 but not on iOS 15.